# How do I make sscanf ignore white spaces? C

Tags: c, scanf, long-format-data

I'm trying to read formatted data with sscanf in this format:

```
"%d,%d,%d"
```

for example,

```
sscanf(buffer, "%d,%d,%d", n1, n2, n3)
```

and it is **critic** that there is no white space between every number, because the input comes like this, for example:

```
109,304,249
194,204,482
```

etc.

But when I give sscanf an input like:

```
13, 56, 89
145,    646,    75
```

it still reads it even though it is not in the specifed format, and should be invalid

Is there is a way to write something such that sscanf will work as I expect it to work?

Comment: No, `sscanf` is not designed to be a strict parser. If you want to enforce strict rules, you have to write the parser yourself.

Answer (score 1):

`scanf` ignores leading whitespace for most conversions, but what you want is the opposite of ignoring whitespace.

You cannot tell `scanf` to error out on a whitespace, but you can detect how many whitespace characters were consumed. For example:

```
  #include <stdio.h>

  int main()
  {
      int first, second, before, after;
      int nread;

      nread = scanf("%d,%n %n%d", &first, &before, &after, &second);
      if (nread != 2) {
          printf ("Error in the input stream, 2 items expected, %d matched\n", nread);
      }
      else if (before != after) {
          printf ("Error in the input stream, %d whitespace characters detected\n", 
                      after-before);
      }
      else {
          printf ("Got numbers %d %d\n", first, second);
      }
  }
```

This detects whitespace before the second input.

Having said that, erroring out on whitespace is probably not a good idea.

Comment: Nit, `scanf()` ignores leading whitespace **except** for the specifiers `"%c"`, `"%[..]"` and `"%n"` `:)`

Answer (score 0):

The `%d` conversion format ignores leading white space as well as an optional `+` sign. If you want a stricter validation, you can:

- use an extra validation phase before or after converting the values.
- use a hand coded conversion that rejects malformed input.

Here are some propositions:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char input[100];
    char verif[100];
    int a, b, c;

    if (fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin)) {
        if (sscanf(input, "%d,%d,%d", &a, &b, &c) == 3) {
            snprintf(verif, sizeof verif, "%d,%d,%d\n", a, b, c);
            if (strcmp(input, verif) == 0) {
                printf("input is valid, a=%d, b=%d, c=%d\n", a, b, c);
                return 0;
            } else {
                printf("input contains extra characters\n");
                return 1;
            }
        } else {
            printf("input does not match the pattern\n");
            return 1;
        }
    } else {
       printf("no input\n");
       return 1;
    }
}
```

You could just check if the input string contains any white space:

```
    if (input[strcspn(input, " \t")] != '\0') {
        printf("input string contains spaces or TABs\n");
    }
```

But negative values, redundant `+` signs and leading zeroes will pass the test (eg: `"-1,+1,+0001"`).

If all values must be positive, you could use `scanf()` to perform a poor man's pattern matching:

```
    if (fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin)) {
        char c1, c2;
        if (sscanf(input, "%*[0-9],%*[0-9],%*[0-9]%c%c", &c1, &c2) == 1 && c1 == '\n') {
            /* input line contains exactly 3 numbers separated by a `,` */
        } else {
            printf("invalid format\n");
        }
    }
```

Note however these remarks:

- redundant leading zeroes would still be accepted by this validation phase (eg: `"00,01,02"`).
- overlong numbers will technically cause undefined behavior in all of the above methods (eg: `"0,0,999999999999999999999999999999"`), But the first approach will detect this problem if the conversion just truncates or maximises the converted value.
- an overlong input line (longer than 98 bytes plus a newline) will be truncated by `fgets()`, leaving the rest of the input for the next read operation. This may be a problem too.

The solution to your problem depends on how strict and concise the validation must be.

Answer (score 0):

One idea to validate the input is to use the regular expression to match three integers delimited by commas without including other characters.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <regex.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    regex_t preg;                               // regex pattern
    int ret;
    int n1, n2, n3;
    char *p;                                    // pointer to a character th the string
    char buffer[BUFSIZ];                        // input buffer

    // compile regex to match three integers delimited by commas
    ret = regcomp(&preg, "^([+-]?[[:digit:]]+,){2}[+-]?[[:digit:]]+$", REG_EXTENDED);
    if (ret) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Compile error of regex\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    while (fgets(buffer, BUFSIZ, stdin)) {
        if ((p = rindex(buffer, '\n'))) *p = 0; // remove trailing newline
        ret = regexec(&preg, buffer, 0, NULL, 0);
        if (!ret) {                             // input matches the regex pattern
            sscanf(buffer, "%d,%d,%d", &n1, &n2, &n3);
            printf("=> %d,%d,%d\n", n1, n2, n3);
        } else {
            printf("Error in the input: %s\n", buffer);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

where `^([+-]?[[:digit:]]+,){2}[+-]?[[:digit:]]+$` is the regex:

- `^` anchors the start of the input string.
- `[+-]?` matches zero or one leading plus or minus sign.
- `[[:digit:]]+,` matches the sequence of digits followed by a comma.
- The parentheses `( pattern )` makes a group of the pattern.
- The quantifier `{2}` specifies the number of repetition of the previous atom (including group).
- `$` anchors the end of the input string.